# useFormStatus() is always false in NextJS

Tags: reactjs, next.js, server-side-rendering, next.js13

I'm trying to use `useFormStatus()` to change UI dynamically when the form is submitted and it's waiting to fetch the data.

I have a form component like

```
function onSubmit(data: z.infer<typeof FormSchema>) {
    requestImg(data).then((imageStringify) => {
      const binaryData = Buffer.from(imageStringify.image);
      const imageBase64 = URL.createObjectURL(
        new Blob([binaryData.buffer], { type: "image/jpeg" } /* (1) */)
      );
      setOpen(true);
      setSource(imageBase64);
    });
  }

  if (isDesktop) {
    return (
      <Form {...form}>
        <form
          onSubmit={form.handleSubmit(onSubmit)}
          className="w-2/3 space-y-6"
        >
        ...
```

with `requestImg(data)` being a server action.

I've then the Button component nested inside the `<form>` in a different *Button.tsx* file

```
import { useFormStatus } from "react-dom";

import { Button } from "@/components/ui/button";

export default function ButtonSub() {
  const { pending } = useFormStatus();

  console.log(pending);

  return (
    <Button className="w-full" type="submit" aria-disabled={pending}>
      {pending ? "Processing..." : "Submit"}
    </Button>
  );
}
```

The issue is that, when I click submit, the button text doesn't change to *"Processing..."*

### EDIT

It seems that works only if you're using the action keyword on the form. I've tried

```
<form
        action={async (formData: FormData) => {
          requestImg(formData).then((imageStringify) => {
            const binaryData = Buffer.from(imageStringify.image);
            const imageBase64 = URL.createObjectURL(
              new Blob([binaryData.buffer], { type: "image/jpeg" } /* (1) */)
            );
            setSource(imageBase64);
            setOpen(true);
          });
        }}
        className="w-2/3 space-y-6"
      >
```

but now the image generated with the byte8Array is broken.
I have an image with a dynamic src filled with

```
const [source, setSource] = useState("");
<img src={source}/>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A solution I found without using the action keyword but still using server action calling it as a function was to use `useTransition()`

```
import { useState, useTransition } from "react";

const [isPending, startTransition] = useTransition();

function onSubmit(data: z.infer<typeof FormSchema>) {
    startTransition(async () => {
        ... do your things ...
```

and the Submit Button client component

```
      <Button
        className="w-full"
        type="submit"
        disabled={isPending}
        aria-disabled={isPending}
      >
        {isPending ? "Processing..." : "Submit"}
      </Button>
```

Answer (score 3):

> It seems that works only if you're using the action keyword on the
> form.

that is true. `useFormStatus` has to be used inside a child component of the form and it kinda watches the state change of the server action. But as far as I know it listens for the `action`. `action` defines the server-side destination for the form data after submission. in the context of the server action, server actions make a post request to the current URL. so it is not listening for form onSubmit, that is why your first code execution is not working.

if you read the [enter link description here](https://react%20formStatuc%20docs)

```
const { pending, data, method, action } = useFormStatus();
```

see the action property, from the docs

> **action:** A reference to the function passed to the action prop on the parent . If there is no parent , the property is null.
> If there is a URI value provided to the action prop, or no action prop
> specified, status.action will be null.

Now server action runs in server context, they get executed on the server but `setState` is client specific code. what you have to do is you have to return a value. in your case:

```
 return imageBase64
```

and using `useFormState` you can access to this state. from [useFormState docs](https://react.dev/reference/react-dom/hooks/useFormState)

```
const [state, formAction] = useFormState(action, null);
```

> The current state of the form, which is initially set to the initial
> state you provided, and after the form is submitted is set to the
> return value of the action you provided.

you should be using this state value inside the component